# Calculate growth rate of a population by Leslie matrix

Tags: population-dynamics, population-biology

We can calculate growth rate of a population by calculate the dominant eigen value of a Leslie matrix. What does this growth rate mean? I think that the growth rate N(t+1)/N(t) is depend on the age structure of N(t)? If the growth rate of a population is less than 1, will the population go extinct?